# Accented character as watermark

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, watermark

I used `<p:watermark>` in my application , The problem I am facing with displaying accented character as watermark. It is ok for English character as watermark.

This is working fine for :

```
<f:view contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" encoding="UTF-8">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <p:inputText id="iddd"></p:inputText>
            <p:watermark for="iddd" value="Activity Type"></p:watermark>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

But if I replace `value` of `<p:watermark>` with `"Type d'Activité"` then the watermaek is not displaying and am getting an error on browser's console.

I am using PF 3.5 with mojarra 2.1.
Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks,

EDIT-1 :
I have attached the console's picture

[image]

EDIT-2 : `<p:outputText value='Type d'Activité'>` prints the correct value.

Comment: Character encoding issue. What's the specific error in the console?

Comment: @kolossus I have edited the question, can you give a look ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `"Type d'Activit&#233;"`?

Comment: @rion18 : I tried but did not work.

Comment: @Diganta - What app server are you running? Your appserver also needs to be configured to use UTF-8 encoding

Comment: @kolossus I am using JBoss7.1, have you seen my `EDIT-2` ? The accented characters are displaying correctly in `p:outputText` but not in `watermark`.